# Difference between one month of calisthenics, and one month gym training

Tags: gym, calisthenics

Would there be a noticeable difference in results between one month of training calisthenics, and one month of weightlifting at a gym?

Comment: Are you talking about overall fitness? Lifting strength? Static strength? Endurance? What sort of a workout are you doing at the gym? Your question lacks sufficient detail to provide any sort of an answer.

Comment: There are different types of strength, speed strength, explosiv strength anf maximal strength and you can train them in different ways via calisthenics, gym and others. .. depending on your goals so you should be more specific what you mean.

Comment: I've been asked this question very often, and in most cases what people mean by _gym workout_  is basically _working with weights_. As experienced athlete (and certified instructor) I can  answer this question - if you reopen it

Comment: Edited and voted for reopening. I cleaned the question up, while hopefully not ruining the asker's intent.

Comment: In my opinion, it's still unclear.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I second that

Comment: @SeanDuggan - That's weird. The question originally seemed perfectly clear to me. Barring grammar, I saw no reason for it to be edited at all, but I tried anyway. The question is pretty simple: How would the results of one month of calisthenics look, compared to the results of one month of training at the gym? What is it that seems unclear?

Comment: Namely that the person asking the question never clarified what exactly a "gym workout" is or what criteria they're judging the two events by. To me, it's like trying to answer a question on Stack Overflow of "What's the difference between doing an application in a function-oriented language and doing an application in an office?" Nikita above has their own interpretation of the question, but that requires us basically writing a new question based on assumptions. Ultimately, if we want to answer calisthenics versus weight-lifting, we should ask that question.

Comment: @Alec along with what Sean says, what kind of gym workout? Weights? Treadmill/exercise bike? Spin classes? Circuit/WOD type workouts? It's not really answerable in the current form, even with the edits.

Comment: @JohnP - I think when someone refers to a gym workout, without explicitly saying what they intend to do, it's a pretty surefire educated guess to assume they're talking about weight training. Especially if they're comparing it to another form of strength training (calisthenics).

Comment: @Alec - That may be so, but that's an assumption. I've got some triathlon friends that say "I'm going to the gym" when they intend to swim. Others that say the same thing for racquetball, step aerobics, etc. "Going to the gym", especially for the big box places, could mean any number of things.

Comment: Yeah, if you're part of a particular group of people, you'd probably do that. But online? Also, if you're asking about this kind of question, it's also a pretty clear indicator.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like this SE is the most nitpicky one. It's been brought up before that pretty much anything that deviates even *a little bit* from the norm, gets closed.

Comment: @Alec: I'm going to be horribly square and say that we'd probably be best off moving that discussion to Meta. :-P But overall, this place is pretty good at being flexible everywhere except for people who apparently missed the site being about fitness and instead want to talk about their diet.

Comment: @Alec - I'd vote to reopen if he clarified what type of gym workout he is asking about. Yes, it's probably about weightlifting, but we'd look pretty silly if he comes back and says racquetball. :)

Comment: Even if we assume the Q is about lifting weights, that's still a huge variety of things on both sides. Calisthenics like just push-ups, or burpees and crunches, or bodyweight CrossFit WODs? Lifting like nine kinds of curls, or powerlifting, or bodybuilding, or Oly lifting, or a dumbbell circuit?